# Need to show image from image path stored in mysql to Crystal Report Viewer in C#(VS 2008)

Tags: c#, mysql, crystal-reports

I need to show the image dynamically in Crystal Report from MySQL image path in c# (Visual studio 2008). I have stored the image path in MySQL DB, but couldnt able to display the image on the CR. Code which i have tested is not working. Lots of goggling done already in this, cant find a solutions still. Please help..!!

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            string Student = "SELECT `photo_path` FROM `tc` WHERE `register_no`= '" + Reg_No + "';";
          //  MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(conn);
            //con.Open();
            MySqlCommand cmd1 = new MySqlCommand(Student, conn);
            MySqlDataReader Detail1 = cmd1.ExecuteReader();
            ReportDocument rptDoc = new ReportDocument();
            MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter(); // .xsd file name
            da.SelectCommand = cmd1;
            da.Fill(dt);
            while (Detail1.Read())
            {
                string image = Detail1.GetString(0);
            }
            Detail1.Close();
            conn.Close();
 dt.Columns.Add("Image", System.Type.GetType("System.Byte[]"));
           FileStream fs;
           //if (File.Exists(Image))
           //{
           //    fs = new FileStream(Image, FileMode.Open);
           //}
           //else
           //{
           //    MessageBox.Show("Please File Not Exist");
           //}
          BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(fs);
           byte[] imgbyte = new byte[fs.Length + 1];
           imgbyte = br.ReadBytes(Convert.ToInt32((fs.Length)));

           foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
           {
               dr["Image"] = imgbyte;
           }
           TC_Report myReport = new TC_Report();
           myReport.SetDataSource(dt);
           crystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = myReport;
           crystalReportViewer1.Refresh();
```

I am adding the full code from the form load of crystal report viewer. Now i am getting a error like  "**you can provide a single value for this parameter" and asks for the discrete value**, if i give any value it doesn't show any report . It generates report with data but not the image if i command the lines below the /////////// which i have marked in the code. I really having a very tough time with this crystal report showing image from database. Whats wrong with the code please help..

```
 //creating an object of Report Document class
    ReportDocument reportDocument = new ReportDocument();
    //creating an object of ParameterField class
    ParameterField paramField = new ParameterField();
    //creating an object of ParameterFields class
    ParameterFields paramFields = new ParameterFields();
    //creating an object of ParameterDiscreteValue class
    ParameterDiscreteValue paramDiscreteValue = new ParameterDiscreteValue();
    paramField.Name = "StudentTC";
    //set the parameter value
    paramDiscreteValue.Value = Reg_No;
    //add the parameter value in the ParameterField object
    paramField.CurrentValues.Add(paramDiscreteValue);
    //add the parameter in the ParameterFields object
    paramFields.Add(paramField);
    //set the parameterfield information in the crystal report
    crystalReportViewer1.ParameterFieldInfo = paramFields;
    MySqlConnection conn;
    MySqlCommand cmd;
    MySqlDataAdapter adap;
    // MessageBox.Show(Reg_No);
    // Code to get data from database 
    conn = new MySqlConnection("Server=localhost; Database=mcet; User ID=root; Password=; charset=utf8;");
    conn.Open();
    cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT T2.photo_path,title, firstname, father_name, mother_name, gender, DATE_FORMAT(dob, '%d-%m-%Y') AS DOB, dobw, nationality, e_mail, religion, caste, community, admission_no, degree, department,DATE_FORMAT(doa, '%d-%m-%Y') AS DOA, DATE_FORMAT(dol, '%d-%m-%Y') AS DOL, lentry FROM student_details T1 LEFT JOIN tc T2 ON T1.register_no = T2.register_no where T1.register_no='" + Reg_No + "' ";
    adap = new MySqlDataAdapter();
    adap.SelectCommand = cmd;
       TC_Dataset StudentDB = new TC_Dataset();
        //var StudentDB = new DataSet();
        StudentDB.Clear();
        adap.Fill(StudentDB, "Student");

        // Create a CrystalReport1 object 
        TC_Report myReport = new TC_Report();
        // Set the DataSource of the report 
        myReport.SetDataSource(StudentDB);
        // Set the Report Source to ReportView 
        crystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = myReport;
       // crystalReportViewer1.Refresh();

       ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        MySqlDataReader Detail1 = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        ReportDocument rptDoc = new ReportDocument();
        while (Detail1.Read())
        {
            string image = Detail1.GetString(0);
        }
        Detail1.Close();
        MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter(); // 
        da.SelectCommand = cmd;
        da.Fill(dt);
        conn.Close();
        dt.Columns.Add("Image", System.Type.GetType("System.Byte[]"));
        FileStream fs;
        fs = new FileStream("E:\\student\\Photo\\" + Reg_No + ".jpg", FileMode.Open);
        //string path = Path.Combine("E:\\student\\Photo\\", Reg_No) + ".jpg";

        //if (File.Exists(path))
        //{
        //    fs = new FileStream("E:\\student\\Photo\\" + Reg_No + ".jpg", FileMode.Open);
        //}
        //else
        //{

        //    MessageBox.Show("Please File Not Exist");

        //}
        BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(fs);
        byte[] imgbyte = new byte[fs.Length + 1];
        imgbyte = br.ReadBytes(Convert.ToInt32((fs.Length)));

        foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
        {
            dr["Image"] = imgbyte;
        }
        TC_Report myReport1 = new TC_Report();
        myReport1.SetDataSource(dt);
        crystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = myReport1;
        crystalReportViewer1.Refresh();
```

Comment: what error are you getting?

Comment: use of unassiged variable fs   in the line BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(fs);

Comment: As error suggests fs has not assigned any value

Comment: @ utility, what i doing wrong in this code, can you figure out

Comment: how to change the code to get the image to the CR

Comment: have you selected image or image_path ?

Comment: i have the image path stored in MySQL db and the image is in the local system folder

Comment: fs = new FileStream(locationhere + "name.jpg", FileMode.Open);

Comment: how to add the path(Location), since its not static path

Comment: as you said you are storing location in db

Comment: yes but i having in string image, while addin it 
 
fs = new FileStream(image + "name.jpg", FileMode.Open);      it doesn't workout

Comment: fs = new FileStream(location with filename, FileMode.Open);

Comment: i m really sorry @ utility, i didnt get it, can you see my code and say what should i add in the "location with filename"

Comment: i have added like this fs = new FileStream("E:\\student\\Photo\\" + Reg_No, FileMode.Open);    Now i am coming with an new error, There is already an open DataReader associated with this Connection which must be closed first.   in line      da.Fill(dt);

Comment: Reg_No contains the image name from database,

Comment: uncomment the codes you have commented and change code as necessary to include file location

Comment: it ask for  "you can provide a single value for this parameter" and asks for the discrete value,  while generating report

Comment: @utility  i need to display only one image per report so how to change the below code (i am following the link which you have given above)   for (int rowNumber = 0; rowNumber < imageDataSet.Tables["TC_dt"].Rows.Count; rowNumber++)
                {
                    string imgName = Server.MapPath(imageDataSet.Tables["TC_dt"].Rows[rowNumber]["Name"].ToString());
                    DisplayImages(imageDataSet.Tables["TC_dt"].Rows[rowNumber], "photo_path", imgName);
                }

Comment: getting error  "Inconvertible type mismatch between SourceColumn 'photo_path' of String and the DataColumn 'photo_path' of Byte[]."

Comment: Have you tried that link ? and also if you need just one image,then change the query in the link

Comment: @utility, Thanks for helping me to get this code to work. i have posted the working code below for others ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@utility, Thanks for helping me out to get this work done.  This code is for storing the image as Blob datatype in MySql and bring it into CR using parameter dynamically.

```
     MySqlConnection conn;
     MySqlCommand cmd;
     MySqlDataAdapter adap;

    // Code to get data from database
    conn = new MySqlConnection("Server=localhost; Database=dbname; User ID=root; Password=; charset=utf8;");
    conn.Open();
    cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT photo_path,title, firstname FROM student_details WHERE `register_no`='" + Reg_No + "' ";
    adap = new MySqlDataAdapter();
    adap.SelectCommand = cmd;



    TC_Dataset StudentDB = new TC_Dataset();    //TC_Dataset is the Dataset name, which you have created.
    StudentDB.Clear();
    adap.Fill(StudentDB, "TC_dt");     // TC_dt is the DataTable name in the Dataset

    // Create a CrystalReport1 object 
    TC_Report myReport = new TC_Report();    //TC_Report is the name of the Crystal Report (rpt file)
    TextObject txt1 = (TextObject)myReport.ReportDefinition.Sections["Section1"].ReportObjects["Text68"]; **//  this is used to send the data from text box to CR (Text68) is the textfield name in CR, Year_leaving contains the date of the textbox as string.**
    txt1.Text = Year_leaving;
    TextObject txt2 = (TextObject)myReport.ReportDefinition.Sections["Section1"].ReportObjects["Text21"];
    txt2.Text = reason_leaving;
    // Set the DataSource of the report
    myReport.SetDataSource(StudentDB);
    // Set the Report Source to ReportView 
    crystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = myReport;  //crystalReportViewer1 is the CR Viewer name which is in the form
```